# System.Threading.Timer working logic and if an unexpected error happens how to handle

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, timer, error-handling

Alright i am using `System.Threading.Timer` objects to regularly fire events

**Q1: As far as i understood it starts new tasks like `Task.Factory.StartNew` am i correct ?**

Here how i use example `System.Threading.Timer` object

```
private static Timer _timer;
 _timer = new Timer(checkWaitingUrls, null, PublicSettings.irTimers_Delayed_Start_MiliSeconds, howManySeconds * 1000);
```

Now i can handle unexpected errors at `Task.Factory.StartNew` like below

```
    Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
    process_Given_Page(drwToProcess);
    });

    myTask.ContinueWith(t => ErrorLogger.LogError
("error " + t), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

**Q2: How can i handle `System.Threading.Timer` callback tasks when an error happened so the application wouldn't crash and timer continues to work?**

I don't want to code complete try catch event inside the timer callback function

Ty very much for answers

c# .net 4.5 WPF

**Edit
I found the answer that use System.Timers.Timer and it will swallow such errors without letting you know however you can't log them**

Comment: Timer is completely separate to Tasks... it's not clear why you're trying to talk about them in the same question.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok it starts thread then ? If so how can i handle those errors ?

Comment: What errors? It would really help if you'd ask *one* question, and do so with more clarity - including a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet timer will fire checkWaitingUrls function as a new thread right ? and if an unexpected errors happens in that started new thread ? We can handle them when we use Tasks as i demonstrated.

Comment: Again, timers and tasks are very different. Your question is still unclear. Please spend some time clarifying it, rather than adding comments. (And no, there's no guarantee that a timer will create more threads - by default it will use the thread pool.)

Comment: @JonSkeet ok what i am asking something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406904/how-to-handle-exception-using-timer-thread-class However i am using System.Threading.Timer